# Installing Python via Ansible when no Python version exists on target machine

Tags: ansible

I am attempting to install Python onto a virtual machine (let refer to this as the 'target machine') with `ansible-playbook`. The target machine has no version of Python installed at all (lightweight Unix version)

From my understanding, most ansible modules will require the target machine to have Python installed on it. However, the raw module does not.

I can't seem to even get the most basic command to work with the raw module, it seems that ansirble is still looking for Python on the target machine. If I manually ssh into the target machine and install Python, then the `ansible-playbook` begins to work.

Error message:

```
fatal: [dev]: FAILED! => 
{"changed": false, "failed": true,
 "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 192.168.99.100 closed.\r\n",  
 "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: /usr/bin/python: not found\r\n",
 "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}
```

file `/host_vars/dev.yml`:

```
#NOTE: I can manually ssh in with the details without a problem
ansible_ssh_port: 22
ansible_user: docker
ansible_ssh_host: 192.168.99.100
ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.docker/machine/machines/default/id_rsa
```

file `playbook.yml`:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: test the raw module
    raw: echo "Hello World"
```

file `hosts`:

```
dev
```

Command I ran:

```
ansible-playbook -i ./hosts ./playbook.yml
```

Why is the raw command looking for Python?

How can I run command with Ansible without the target machine having Python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not the `raw` module, but fact-gathering that tries to run Python.

Add:

```
gather_facts: no
```

Comment: Thanks @techraf, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: I don't know if ansible accepts "no" as a keyword but in the documentation says: `gather_facts: False`. Hope it helps :)